# Gulp sass is eating the scss file without giving any errors

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I've been started using gulp few days ago, and I had to tackle many problems it was very hard to fix errors in a non-compiling languages and their runtime is slow as well.

Unfortunately last problem I've found is very different, it does not give any error but just eats up the file from stream.

To summarize the problem in less words here is the portion of gulpfile.js:

```js
gulp.src([ folder.src + "scss/vendor/_bootstrap.scss" ], { allowEmpty: true })
    .pipe(debug())                          // file exists
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(debug())                          // file exists
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError)) // scss to css
    .pipe(debug())                          // file doesn't exist
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        overrideBrowserslist: ["last 2 versions"]
    }))
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(cleanCSS()) // minifies css
    .pipe(rename({
        // rename bootstrap.css to bootstrap.min.css
        suffix: ".min"
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./")) // source maps for bootstrap.min.css
    .pipe(gulp.dest(out));
```

The first two debug statements outputs that there is a file in the stream of gulp pipes, while after running the `sass()` on the pipe the file immediately vanishes, no notice or errors.

```js
[20:21:45] Starting 'css'...
[20:21:45] gulp-debug: src/main/resources/assets/scss/vendor/_bootstrap.scss
[20:21:45] gulp-debug: src/main/resources/assets/scss/vendor/_bootstrap.scss
[20:21:45] gulp-debug: 1 item
[20:21:45] gulp-debug: 1 item
[20:21:45] gulp-debug: 0 items
[20:21:45] gulp-debug: 0 items
[20:21:45] Finished 'css' after 169 ms
```

**Isn't it strange? How would I solve this problem. No stack-trace, no errors, no warnings :(**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually files prefixed with an underscore(`_`) were ignored by the sass function. Probably because they represent partials for sass.

Piping the stream via rename and using a simple regex solves the problem:

```js
gulp.src([ folder.src + "scss/vendor/_bootstrap.scss" ], { allowEmpty: true })
// ...
.pipe(rename(function(opt) {
    opt.basename = opt.basename.replace(/^_/, '');  // renames files starting with _
    return opt;
}))
.pipe(sass())
// ...
```